# JS Render For Loop in child JSON object

Tags: json, jsrender

Trying to make this work. I need to display FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME values beetween to new TDs. The value are stored in an object of the data item. I can't seem to loop througt the child object.

Template example

```
<script id="row_tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
      <tr id="{{>id}}">
        <td class="textC">{{>id}}</td>
        <td class="">{{>email}}</td>
        {{for data}}

            ??????

        {{/for}}
      </tr>
</script>
```

Here is an example of the json object sent to the template ( actually, data.results is sent to the template )

```
{
  "results":[
     {
     "id":"1",
     "email":"aaaa@test.com",
     "data":{
        "1":{
           "first_name":{
              "value":"Name 1",
              "public":"1",
              "field":"1",
              "mandatory":"1",
              "possible_value":"",
              "type":"text"
           },
           "last_name":{
              "value":"Name 2",
              "public":"1",
              "field":"2",
              "mandatory":"1",
              "possible_value":"",
              "type":"text"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  {
     "id":"2",
     "email":"test2@test.com",
     "data":{
        "2":{
           "first_name":{
              "value":"Name 3",
              "public":"0",
              "field":"1",
              "mandatory":"1",
              "possible_value":"",
              "type":"text"
           },
           "last_name":{
              "value":"Name 4",
              "public":"0",
              "field":"2",
              "mandatory":"1",
              "possible_value":"",
              "type":"text"
           }
        }
     }
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a poorly structured response. I should **not** need to know the `id` of `data`'s parent to access its children. Also, `data` isn't an array.

```
<script id="row_tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
      <tr id="{{>id}}">
        <td class="textC">{{>id}}</td>
        <td class="">{{>email}}</td>
        <td class="">{{>data.{{:id}}.first_name.value}}</td>
        <td class="">{{>data.{{:id}}.lastt_name.value}}</td>
      </tr>
</script>
```